# Add audio player to active admin panel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a Blog that accepts comments with audios files attached with Rails 6.

Is it possible to show the audios and listen to them in the active admin dashboard?

I have

```
#/models/comment.rb
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user

  has_one_attached :audio_file
end
```

```
#/admin/comments.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Comment do
  actions :all, except: [:edit, :new]
  permit_params :audio_file, :post_id, :created_at, :deleted_by
end
```

I have try adding

```
  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :audio_file
    column :challenge_id
    column :created_at
    column :deleted_by
    actions
  end
```

But it just add the text `audio_file`.

How can I add the `audio_tag` with the `audio_file` attached?

Comment: you may want to consider marking your question as solved

Answer (score 2):

Use [`audio_tag` helper method](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/audio_tag) like so:

```ruby
index do
  selectable_column
  id_column
  column :audio_file do |comment|
    if comment.audio_file.attached?
      audio_tag(comment.audio_file, autoplay: false, controls: true)
    else
      # Do whatever needed
    end
  end
  column :challenge_id
  column :created_at
  column :deleted_by
  actions
end
```

`audio_tag` supports native [`audio` Embed Audio element attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#attributes).